# dcast produces extremely wide dataframe

Tags: r, casting, reshape

I'm trying to transform data that looks like this:

```
> long.data
         date      ID  average    stat
5128 20020510   UKM66 42.51919 minimum
2267 20020510   PL622 61.31768 average
265  20020503   DE71E 42.17819 maximum
```

where `average` is identified by a combination of `date`, `ID` and `stat`, into something that looks like this:

```
> wide.data
      date    ID minimum average maximum
1 20020510 UKM66      50      62      70
2 20020510 PL622      52      60      63
3 20020510 DE71E      49      67      80
```

As far as I can tell, `dcast` would be a great way of doing this, but when I try the following:

```
> wide.data <- dcast(long.data, date + ID + stat ~ average)
```

I get a warning and a horrendously long dataframe:

```
Using stat as value column: use value.var to override.
> ncol(wide.data)
[1] 4577
```

It seems that R is giving me a column for every unique observation value. I've read the documentation on `reshape2` and `dcast`, but I'm still just not getting it right. What's going wrong here?

Comment: You want `dcast(long.data, date + ID ~ stat, value.var="average")`. `dcast` will give you a new column for every unique value (or combination of values, for multiple variables) of the variable to the right of the `~`.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding what's actually being calculated. Which column has the values from which the "average", "maximum", and "minimum" are supposed to be derived? And why should that data example produce the result that is offered as the desired output?

Comment: average in long.data contains all the values. I admit it's confusing that stat sometimes contains "average".

Comment: @eipi10 solved it. If you write it as an answer, I'll make sure to accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `dcast(long.data, date + ID ~ stat, value.var="average")`. `dcast` will give you a new column for every unique value (or combination of values, for multiple variables) of the variable to the right of the `~`.